# Ant Design : getFieldDecorator()

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
import {
 Form, Input, Tooltip, Icon
} from 'antd';
 import React , {Component }from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class RegistrationForm extends Component {
     state = {
     confirmDirty: false,
     autoCompleteResult: [],
     };

     handleSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
         if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          }
       });
       }

     handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
         const value = e.target.value;
         this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value                
         });
         }

        render() {
           console.log(this.props.form)
             const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

             const formItemLayout = {
             labelCol: {
                   xs: { span: 24 },
                   sm: { span: 8 },
                 },
              wrapperCol: {
                  xs: { span: 24 },
                  sm: { span: 16 },
              },
             };

return (
  <Form {...formItemLayout} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Item
      label="E-mail"
      >
      {getFieldDecorator('email', {
        rules: [{
          type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
        }, {
          required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
        }],
      })(
        <Input />
        )}
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item
      label={(
        <span>
          Nickname&nbsp;
          <Tooltip title="What do you want others to call you?">
            <Icon type="question-circle-o" />
          </Tooltip>
        </span>
      )}
      >
      {getFieldDecorator('nickname', {
        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your nickname!', whitespace: true }],
      })(
        <Input />
        )}
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
);
  }
   }
```

I am using `ant design` but when I run this code it says `this.props.form is undefined`. In this line when I declare `getFieldDecorator` in `render` function.

Please tell from where are these props coming and how to use it ? I do not have any parent component that is passing any `prop`. help fix it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please export your component like

```
export default Form.create()(RegistrationForm)
```

Comment: In antd 4, you do not need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should export a class like this:

```
export default Form.create()(RegistrationForm)
```

The form object will be inject to props by this way.

Answer (score 2):

I used this way

```
const WerappedRegistration = Form.create({ name: 'registrationform' })(RegistrationForm);
export default WerappedRegistration;
```