# How to use the getFieldDecorator with react (function) hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, antd

I am trying to create a simple antd form but dont know how to make the getFieldDecorator to work with my react function. how do i translate `this.props.form` to the react hooks approach? 
This is the class syntax from antd documentation.

```
  function FormDrawerButton () {

  // ToggleDrawer
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setVisible(!visible)
  }

const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form; // how to use this?

  return (
    <>
    <Button
      type="primary"
      icon="edit"
      size="large"
      style={{ float: 'right' }}
      onClick={ toggleDrawer }
    >
      Add user
    </Button>
  <div>
    <Drawer
      title="Create a new user"
      width={720}
      onClose={ toggleDrawer }
      visible={ visible }
    >
    <p>Form</p>
    <Form className="login-form">
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              placeholder="Username"
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>
    </Drawer>
  </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default FormDrawerButton
```

Comment: Did you create Form with Form.create()(React.createClass({... syntax

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107026/ant-design-getfielddecorator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This answer is for version 3 of antd.

You need to wrap your component with [`Form.create`](https://ant.design/components/form/#Formcreate(options)), then the `form` object will be injected to your component's props.

Just reference it afterward:

```
function FormDrawerButton(props) {
  ...

  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
}

export default Form.create()(FormDrawerButton);
```

Here is code-sandbox example of a form in functional component [from my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289639/input-onchange-checker-if-data-exist-in-json-data):

[image: Edit Q-58289639-FormFieldValidate]

Comment: currently, this fails with

**_antd.Form.create(...) is not a function**

Comment: @MariusB its for version 3, for version 4 there is new API, I updated antd version in the sandbox

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that for v4.0 Tabs `forceRender` is broken so I cannot upgrade....

Answer (score 0):

If using class component then use`const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;`
and if use functional component then use `const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;`

because (this.) use for object reference in-class component required reference but functional component not required.